# Galaxybase client: "Unable to acquire connection from the pool within the configured maximum time of 60000ms."

Tags: graph-databases

The client is encountering the following prompt: "Unable to acquire connection from the pool within the configured maximum time of 60000ms."

I reviewed the code logic and observed that there were no available connections in the connection pool. Additionally, the maximum limit for requesting connections had been reached. What should be done next to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The Reason of your problem is: The connection didn't consume the server's data correctly after executing the request, causing the client to wait for the request.

Solution: review code logic to verify if there is any unconsumed data in StatementResult or the method that makes the return value of Graph an iterator.